# Reverse organization policies on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-office, office365

I installed my work's Office 365 Plus on my home machine while I work at home. At some point in the installation, it asked me if I wanted to use my organization's policies or not. At the time, I didn't think much of it, and said yes. Office installed fine and I went about my business.

A few days later, though ... Windows demands I change my PIN code "because of my organization's policies." And when I go into settings, I'm told that "some settings are managed by (my) organization." For example, here's Windows Update now:

[image]

I don't want these organization policies on my machine, mandating when I must change my PIN or passwords, and what I can and can't change about my settings.

How can I reverse this? Would installing do it? Or some deeper fix?

By the way, uninstalling does not fix this problem.

Comment: *Have you checked with your organization?* You state you are still working at home, so those rules still apply. Yes, it's a nuisance, but is it worth your job?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me -- my job is not at risk at all. Also, I don't really need Office for my work. I'd rather have full control of my personal machine and lose Office; I'm just asking for help how to proceed.

Comment: Uninstall it and install free LibreOffice. Hopefully, that will also uninstall the policies.

Comment: There is an option within Settings -> Accounts to disconnect your school or work account.  Have you tried that? Uninstalling Office will not revert the changes made to your system nor will they prevent, the policies from being enforced, you have to disconnect your work account for that to happen.

Comment: Settings -> Accounts, but where?